# Inequality of Integrals of step functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi, \psi$ be two real valued step functions defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$. I need to show if the following inequality holds or not: $$ (I(\phi \cdot \psi))^2\leq (I(\phi))² \cdot (I(\psi))²$$
where $I$ means the integral of the step function.
After trying to decompose the (finite) sum of the product by means of the triangle inequality, I could not find a suitable way to approximate the sum by something which would refer to a product of integrals . I also considered to use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality but I became doubtful about it. In order to prove that the inequality is false a counterexample will suffice.

I will appreciate a solution proposal or some hints.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi=\chi_{[0,1/2]},\psi=\chi_{[1/4,1/2]}$, $\phi\psi=\chi_{[1/4,1/2]}$, $I(\phi\psi)^{2}=1/16$, $I(\phi)^{2}=1/4, I(\psi)^{2}=1/16$, so the inequality is not true.

Comment: Thanks. How did you approach the problem ? I tried for an hour, and I couldn't make it.

Comment: You know this is no Cauchy-Schwarz, so it shouldn't be that nice, so the very first step is to test the simplest case that when the step functions consisted of only one term, that is, the characteristic function on a set, of course, you don't do coefficients in front to test it because it is less convenient.

Comment: @user284331 $\phi=\chi_{[0,1/2]}$, what does the chi mean here? Some special function?

Comment: The function with value $1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and zero otherwise.